# insertFileFromBase64 method throwing error if any emebeded object is linked to the word document

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Here i am inserting a document from my word add-in. Every normal document is inserting successfully except the document which has embeded object (other word,excel etc file). is there any way to insert that type of document too? giving a part of the code snippet.

```
//datainbase64 = base64 string.
//insertionType = start/end/replace
range.insertFileFromBase64(datainbase64, insertionType);

                    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
                    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
                    return context.sync().then(function() {.......
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"ooxmlIsMalformated","errorLocation":"Range.insertFileFromBase64","statement":"var insertFileFromBase64=selection.insertFileFromBase64(...);","surroundingStatements":["var root=context.root;","var selection=root.getSelection();","// Instantiate {selection}","// >>>>>","var insertFileFromBase64=selection.insertFileFromBase64(...);","// <<<<<","// Instantiate {insertFileFromBase64}"],"fullStatements":["var root=context.root;","var selection=root.getSelection();","// Instantiate {selection}","var insertFileFromBase64=selection.insertFileFromBase64(.....

Comment: Sorry, this went off my radar... I'm guessing that the problem comes from the *relationships* that manage how a Word document works with embedded content and/or the fact that the type being embedded isn't presently "valid" in the target document.

Comment: A Word document is a zip file containing XML, media and other file types. These are linked together using *relationships* stored in *rels* files with IDs to where the content should be displayed in the main part of the document. Possibly, the Relationships aren't being created, or the ID being imported doesn't match... or the defined file types for the document don't contain the embedded object type.